# What meaning does "within" have in this case?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

So I was reading this scientific article and stumbled upon the following phrase:

> "winL is a subset of partL also containing **objects within epsilon of
>   r**."

It's refering to distances as shown in the picture below (the gray part is winL, which contains *the objects positioned within epsilon meters of r*).

What exactly does it mean? I'm not a native English speaker and I don't know how to explain this.

**Later edit: So I figured out a better, less technical example, inspired from the first answer. What does within mean when you say: "*x is within an arbitrarily small distance of r*"**.

[image: Ride like the wind]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Epsilon* just indicates an arbitrarily small value. It comes from the [epsilon-delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) technique used in mathematical analysis.

So, "within epsilon meters of r" just means "within an arbitrarily small distance of r". That is, the distance between p<sub>2</sub> and p<sub>1</sub> must not be less than r - ε or greater than r + ε.

This looks like something from perturbation theory.

Comment: Yes, but how do you explain "within an arbitrarily small distance of r"? Does that actually mean "positioned between r-epsilon and r+epsilon"?

Comment: @HelloLili See my edits.